# How to add specific number to the variable if some condition is true with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a specific integer to the a variable if some condition is true.
For Example

```
 var x = some integer;
 if (some condition)
 add 1 to value of x
```

My code: 
**Html**

```
<form id="f1">
<p class="Q1">CSS stand for</p><br>
<input name="a1" value="A" type="checkbox" id="q1aa1" >Styling Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="B" type="checkbox" id="q1aa2" >Style Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="C" type="checkbox" id="q1aa3" >Cascading style sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="D" type="checkbox" id="q1aa4" >None of these<br>
<input type="button" id="check1" value="check1" /><br />
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){
var x = 0;  
    $('#check1').click(function() {
        if($('#q1aa3').is(':checked')) {
        1 + x.val
    }
   });      

});
```

Please Help!!

Comment: You want to increment x by 1??? Your question is unclear but it seems really really basic programming question. You should put some effort for sure...

Comment: specific integer to the which variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( function() {
    var x = 0;  
    if ($('.Q1 input').is(':checked')) {
        x=x+1;
    }
    else
    {
        x=x-1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="f1">
<p class="Q1">CSS stand for</p><br>
<input name="a1" value="A" type="checkbox" id="q1aa1" >Styling Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="B" type="checkbox" id="q1aa2" >Style Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="C" type="checkbox" id="q1aa3" >Cascading style sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="D" type="checkbox" id="q1aa4" >None of these<br>
<input type="button" id="check1" value="check1" /><br />
</form>
<script>
var x = 0;  
$('#check1').click(function() {
    if($('#q1aa3').is(':checked')) {
    x=x+1;
    alert(x);
}
});      
</script>
```

Remove Alert or modify variables according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var x = 0;var cur_val;  
    $("#check1").click(function(){ 

        if($('#q1aa1').is(':checked')) {
             cur_val = parseInt($('#q1aa1').val());
             x = x + cur_val;
             $('#test').html(x);
        }

        if($('#q1aa2').is(':checked')) {
             cur_val = parseInt($('#q1aa1').val());
             x = x + cur_val;
             $('#test').html(x);
        } 

        if($('#q1aa3').is(':checked')) {
             cur_val = parseInt($('#q1aa1').val());
             x = x + cur_val;
             $('#test').html(x);
        }  

        if($('#q1aa4').is(':checked')) {
             cur_val = parseInt($('#q1aa1').val());
             x = x + cur_val;
             $('#test').html(x);
        } 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="f1">
<p class="Q1">CSS stand for</p><br>
<input name="a1" value="1" type="checkbox" id="q1aa1" >Styling Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="2" type="checkbox" id="q1aa2" >Style Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="3" type="checkbox" id="q1aa3" >Cascading style sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="4" type="checkbox" id="q1aa4" >None of these<br>
<input type="button" id="check1" value="check1" /><br />
</form>
<div id="test"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var x = 0;var cur_val;  
    $(".check_class").click(function(){ 
       cur_val = parseInt($(this).val());
       x = x + cur_val;
       $('#test').html(x);        
    });
});

<form id="f1">
<p class="Q1">CSS stand for</p><br>
<input name="a1" value="1" class="check_class" type="checkbox" id="q1aa1" >Styling Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="2" class="check_class" type="checkbox" id="q1aa2" >Style Sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="3" class="check_class" type="checkbox" id="q1aa3" >Cascading style sheets<br>
<input name="a1" value="4" class="check_class" type="checkbox" id="q1aa4" >None of these<br>
<input type="button" id="check1" value="check1" /><br />
</form>
<div id="test"></div>
```

I did not get what you want exactly, that is why i gave the previous code.